# How to calculate an average from an nested join Query?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to query the average of a column named `watts` from a `consumption` table for each `appliance` that each registry is linked to, but I must separate each value on behalf of the `proto` and `user` to whom said info belongs.

Therefore I have to join each table that will ultimately link the user to my query. I was able to accomplish the second half of this task. However, when I try to calculate said average using the `AVG()` function an error shows up in MySQL.

> ## 1140 - In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains non-aggregated column moniref.cr.idConsumption'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I've tried this query which actually works in the sense that shows only the user's '1' registries, but can't find a way to properly calculate the average for each appliance.

```
SELECT
  cr.idConsumption,
  AVG(cr.watts),
  a.idApliance,
  p.idProto
FROM
  consumptionregistry cr
INNER JOIN
  apliance a
ON
  a.idApliance = cr.apliance_idApliance
INNER JOIN
  proto_has_apliance phs
ON
  phs.apliance_idApliance = a.idApliance
INNER JOIN
  proto p
ON
  phs.Proto_idProto = p.idProto AND p.user_idUser=1
```

I'm expecting to see something like this:
    [image: Succ Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would seem to need a `group by`:

```
SELECT a.idApliance, AVG(cr.watts), a.idApliance
FROM consumptionregistry cr INNER JOIN
     apliance a
     ON a.idApliance = cr.apliance_idApliance INNER JOIN
     proto_has_apliance phs
     ON phs.apliance_idApliance = a.idApliance INNER JOIN
     proto p
     ON phs.Proto_idProto = p.idProto AND p.user_idUser = 1
GROUP BY a.idApliance;
```

Answer (score 0):

Any column that uses an aggregate function such as `AVG()`, `MIN()`, `MAX()` are "aggregating" columns. The others are "NON-aggregating".

```
SELECT
  cr.idConsumption,  this is NON-aggregating
  AVG(cr.watts),     this is aggregating
  a.idApliance,      this is NON-aggregating
  p.idProto          this is NON-aggregating
```

**All NON-aggregating columns must appear in the group by clause.** In most databases using SQL that is true all the time, in MySQL that is true when a server setting `sql_mode` is set to `only_full_group_by`. So if you now re-read your error message it should hopefully be clear:

There are 3 non-aggregating columns; All 3 should be listed in a group by clause.

Link for more on [`sql_mode`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html)

---

`#1140 - In aggregated query without GROUP BY,`

An "aggregated query without GROUP BY" refers to something like this:

```
select count(*) from consumptionregistry;
```

and, that example doesn't need a `GROUP BY` clause. But as soon as you include a "non-aggregated" column in the select, you do need `GROUP BY`